# Why progress bar always shows 100%?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, office365

I'm working with office 365 [progress bar](https://dev.office.com/fabric#/components/progressindicator). I got data for it (percents) from websocket. Now I have next code:

```
export default class NotificationBar extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this._async = new Async(this);
    }

    render(){
        let { process } = this.props;// this object I get from flux store, it refreshes when web socket  updates

        return (
                    <ProgressIndicator
                        percentComplete={ this._getProgress() } />
        )
    };

    _getProgress = () => {
        let { process } = this.props;//here this.props.process.percent updates
        return process.percent;
    };
}
```

After page load progress bar becomes 100% and doesnt change, though I get percents from method.  I tried to experiment and put in component's render:

- percentComplete={ 0 } -progressbar is empty
- percentComplete={ any number > 0 } progressbar displays 100%

What can be the reason of such behavior? Where I made the mistake?

Comment: You are saying that there exists a `this.props.percent` but you are returning `this.props.process.percent`. Which one is it? :)

Comment: there is a mistake. it must be this.props.process.percent.allready corrected

Comment: Is percentComplete between 0 and 1?

Comment: no, I put integers before this moment. now I tried .5 and got 50%..

Comment: @SamFisher, so it works now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `percentComplete` must be a number between 0 and 1. If you use more than 1 it will count as 100%.

In programming this behavior is widely used, as `50%` is just `50/100 = 0.5`, for example.